# NodeJs get callback from function after some time

Tags: node.js, function, error-handling, callback, chat

I am developing a chatbot in nodejs , When a user sends a message, it comes to MAIN function, from there the sub functions will be executed and callback the output to MAIN function. If I got any error in sub function I didn't get any callback. At this time, I have to send error message to user. So If I didn't get any callback from sub function within 10 secs, then there may be an error in the sub function. So how can I identify error or send callback to MAIN function? Please help me. I can't put more error checks in all my sub functions.

Comment: What kinds of errors will occur in the subfunctions? Throws?

Comment: like logical errors , string handling errors, declaration and initialization errors

Comment: Do you have control over the subfunctions' definitions? Or are they from a package/library? In some cases, errors are provided through a separate event, requiring you to register an additional handler to receive them. But, if the functions are completely swallowing/discarding any errors that may be occurring rather than passing them along, they should be rewritten to avoid that (or you should consider finding a different package/library that is written idiomatically/properly).

Comment: I developed all subfunctions , I have control over them. But sometimes I am missing some error checks and declaration and wrong variable accessing problems . In that case ,program is getting stopped without any log message. How to easily identify this ?

Comment: I think try {  } catch { }  solve my problem. is there any other way ?

Comment: You need to show code.  Even if it's a small repro exhibiting the problem. (doesn't have to be a dump of full code).  Can't help without seeing code.